# Gutenberg Richtext component tabs the user out of field after one keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Richtext component tabs the user out of field after one keystroke
Video of the bug can be found here: https://youtu.be/yIH3-tsyiDI

Gist code: https://gist.github.com/martinowren/b6c8993d9b72e9b61d605b3832690811

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Add the block
Click on 'Legg til partner'
Click on the richtext component and try to do multple keystrokes
See error

Expected behavior: The user should be able to write coninusly

Comment: If this is a bug as you say, shouldn't you be posting this on the [Gutenberg GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg) instead? Why post here?

Comment: It has been posted to the Gutenberg issue tracker. Posted here hoping someone would see a clear solution.